# Kong Ingress Controller - Remove Kong related headers

Tags: kubernetes, kong, response-headers, kong-ingress

I have a working installation of Kong on a Kubernetes cluster, using kubernetes-ingress-controller functionality (https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller).

I would like to remove the following Kong's related headers:

- "X-Kong-Upstream-Latency"
- "X-Kong-Proxy-Latency"
- "Via"
- "Server"

I tried by using the response-transformer plugin by applying the following KongPlugin resource:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: kong-response-transformer
config:
  remove:
    headers:
    - "X-Kong-Upstream-Latency"
    - "X-Kong-Proxy-Latency"
    - "Via"
    - "Server"
plugin: response-transformer
```

But only the "Server" header is removed from responses. Is there a way to remove such headers from response in a "kubernetes-ingress-controller" way by using some custom resources?

I found several GitHub issues related to this problem ([1](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1009), [2](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1315)) but all of them refers to the possibility to update the Kong configuration file (/etc/kong/kong.yml) and I honestly don't know how to apply such changes in my Kubernetes environment. Passing the following lines into a ConfigMap does not fix the problem:

```
# Add additional response headers
header_filter_by_lua_block {
    kong.header_filter()
    ngx.header["Server"] = nil
    ngx.header["Via"] = nil
    ngx.header["X-Kong-Proxy-Latency"] = nil
    ngx.header["X-Kong-Upstream-Latency"] = nil
}
```

Any help on this?
Thank you...

Edit: Kong version is 2.0.3, kong-ingress-controller version is 0.8.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable these headers via the [`headers`](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/configuration/#headers) configuration property. Also noted on the same page is the fact that configuration properties can also be specified as [environment variables](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/configuration/#environment-variables).

You can thus update your Deployment to specify the `headers = off` property as an environment variable. Something similar to:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-kong
  namespace: kong
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        name: proxy
        image: kong:2.0.3
        env:
        - name: KONG_HEADERS
          value: off
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem and fixed it after finding this thread.
As I'm directly building Docker image of kong, I added below step in Docker file to inject the to inject the environment variable

```
ENV KONG_HEADERS='off'
```

Answer (score 0):

@thibaultcha is right.
looking at the https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/9f2b1d984057336cc6075c287ec38ad59323fe6e/kong.conf.default#L656
We can see the definition of the headers.
the headers environment is changed to `KONG_HEADERS`

all that needs to be done when using Helm is to add to the values.yaml file the headers with "off"

```
env:
  headers: 'off'
```